# Переменная не меняет значение

Tags: c#, winforms

Ну столкнулся с такой проблемой, что переменная как с самого начала было 0 так и осталась. По сути должна принять значение от пары "ключ-значение" и прибавить его к переменной, ну а дальше вывести в label7(верхний).
На скриншоте после того как я ввёл букву нажал на кнопку ход и показывает 0.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int gets = 0;
        string word = textBox1.Text;
        List<char> wordsPart = new List<char>();
        foreach (char c in word)
        {
            wordsPart.Add(c);
        }
        foreach (char ch in wordsPart)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<char,int> item in latterScore)
            {
                if (item.Key == ch)
                    gets += item.Value;
            }
        }
        label7.Text = gets.ToString();
    }
    Dictionary<char, int> latterScore = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    public void InitializeLatters()
    {
        latterScore.Add('а', 1);
        latterScore.Add('б', 2);
        latterScore.Add('в', 1);
        latterScore.Add('г', 3);
        latterScore.Add('д', 2);
        latterScore.Add('е', 1);
        latterScore.Add('ё', 3);
        latterScore.Add('ж', 5);
        latterScore.Add('з', 5);
        latterScore.Add('и', 1);
        latterScore.Add('й', 4);
        latterScore.Add('к', 2);
        latterScore.Add('л', 2);
        latterScore.Add('м', 2);
        latterScore.Add('н', 1);
        latterScore.Add('о', 1);
        latterScore.Add('п', 2);
        latterScore.Add('р', 1);
        latterScore.Add('с', 1);
        latterScore.Add('т', 1);
        latterScore.Add('у', 2);
        latterScore.Add('ф', 10);
        latterScore.Add('х', 5);
        latterScore.Add('ц', 5);
        latterScore.Add('ч', 5);
        latterScore.Add('ш', 8);
        latterScore.Add('ь', 3);
        latterScore.Add('ы', 5);
        latterScore.Add('э', 8);
        latterScore.Add('ъ', 10);
        latterScore.Add('ю', 8);
        latterScore.Add('я', 3);
        latterScore.Add('*', 0);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: InitializeLatters() не забыли вызвать?

Comment: Такие проблемы легко решаются с помощью отладчика. Обязательно учитесь им пользоваться.

Comment: о Господи. Забыл. Это просто второй раз переписываю программу и незаметил такой якобы мелочи

Comment: Всё отлично заработало! Спасибо.

Comment: Ага, достаточно было бы просто поставить брейкпоинт и при остановке просто навести курсор на `latterScore`, чтобы убедиться что в нем `Count: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это, конечно, не ответ на вопрос, но я не удержался от рефакторинга вашего кода. 
Вот код, который делает то же самое, что ваш

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    label7.Text = textBox1.Text
        .Where(c=>latterScore.ContainsKey(c))
        .Sum(c=>latterScore[c]).ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Неплохо бы тогда уж и `InitializeLatters` отрефакторить ;)

Comment: ну, с `InitializeLatters()` я ещё могу смириться, но от работы со словарем у меня внутри немного ёкнуло )

Comment: @tym32167 а как можно инициализатор изменить?

Comment: @SeeSharp думаю, тут имелось ввиду вместо 100500 дообавлений вручную в словарь, использовать [инициализатор словаря](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer)

Comment: @tym32167 ага понял, спасибо